# Batch file: Copy all files and folder except one folder

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I made a .bat file to copy some files, like backup and i need to copy all except one folder.
I have, for example, folder test, and subfolders bin, log, Account... and some more files and i want to copy all files and folders except folder "log".

This is my code for copy all:

if not exist "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\backup\test" xcopy "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\backup\test" /s /i

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) command instead, it has `/XD` to exclude directories by name.

```
robocopy "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\backup\test" *.* /XD "log" /S
```